# Different past tense for various *et words

Tags: verbs

The past tense of Bet, Let, and Set are Bet, Let, and Set; but the past tense of Jet, Net, Pet, Vet, and Wet are Jetted, Netted, Petted, Vetted, and Wetted.  Is there a reason for this difference?

Comment: Yes, there very much is. Let me see whether I can't find the duplicate.

Comment: Not necessary for "*bet*". It's past tense can also be "*betted*" - https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=DwdsXYaOG9uy9QPx07y4Cg&q=betted&oq=betted&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i10l9.189275.190582..191651...0.4..0.143.756.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131j0i131i67j0i67i70i249.K2Ro6EYlP7Q&ved=0ahUKEwjG0e31mbDkAhVbWX0KHfEpD6cQ4dUDCAo&uact=5

Comment: [Related answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396328/irregular-verbs-in-english-why-do-so-many-end-in-d/397616#397616)

Comment: Bet, let and set are all words descended from Old English verbs. All the others that you mentioned are have other origins (Old French and Gaelic for instance), except for "wet", which is also Old English in origin and which can also be an irregular verb with three identical forms. I think that's at least one of the reasons why it's so.

Comment: You left out *get / got*....

Comment: Note that 'set' has the past simple and past participle 'setted'  when used in the 'put in [say Year 10] sets'.

Comment: "He wet his pants," not, "He wetted his pants."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman But _wetted_ can be used for deliberately applying moisture to something, as in "He wetted his finger before turning the page".

Comment: two syllables: to abet  and to allot, abetted and allotted.

Answer (score 10):

There is a set of English irregular verbs that have four unusual characteristics:

1. they consist of only one syllable
2. they end in a dental stop, /d/ or /t/
3. they have a lax or low vowel - /ɛ ɪ æ ɔ ʊ ə ɚ/
4. they are not inflected for past tense or past participle

Examples are the verbs *bet, let, set*, as noted, but also others, like *cut, spit,* and *cast*.
There are around 25 verbs in the list:

- *beat,
  bet,
  bid,
  burst,
  cast,
  cost,
  cut,
  fit,
  hit,
  hurt,
  knit,
  let,
  put,
  quit,

  rid,
  set,
  shed,
  shut,
  slit,
  spit,
  split,
  spread,
  thrust,
  upset,
  wed.*

As can be seen, the verbs *jet, net, pet, wet,* and *vet* are not in the list,
so those are regular verbs with regular past tense forms in *-ed*.

Why those verbs and not others? Because that's the way irregularities work.
Irregular verbs do not happen by rule -- *irregular* **means** 'not by rule'.

Comment: I don't know whether it's necessary to restrict this category to verbs with lax vowels. There are also verbs that have a long vowel in the present but a short vowel in the past tense/participle, like *read/read, lead/led, feed/fed, breed/bred, meet/met.*

Comment: I don't think that's necessary; it's just characteristic. The defining characteristic is the zero-affixation in the principal parts: _set, set, set; quit, quit, quit; put, put, put._ That's the set determiner; the other properties just turn out to be common; dunno why. It can be expanded into the whole manifold of strong verbiage, but I'd rather not, thanks. :-)

Comment: @sumelic _Beat_, which is the first on the list in the answer, doesn’t have a lax vowel either, not even in the past; and _beat_ and _bid_ also inflect for past participle. (Also, _wet_ is absolutely on the list for me in some senses. “He wet himself” sounds absolutely bizarre to me with a weak past-tense form. _Pet_ is also common enough with a zero-past, though probably still more common with a regular past.)

Comment: Well, there obviously *does* seem to be a reason why. They all end in /t/. Adding a syllable final /t/ to a word ending in a voiceless consonant is the normal method of addending the past tense morpheme. But English won't allow a geminate /tt/ to do that job when the base verb ends in /t/. For most verbs ending in /t/, the solution is to insert a vowel between the verb-final /t/ and its suffix. However another solution is to delete the /t/-suffix altogether.

Comment: NB "spit" [inflects to "spat"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spit), at least where I come from :)

Comment: Is *pit* part of this group? I remember a discussion on the point, but not the conclusion reached.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the words with irregular past forms are very old (derived from Old or Middle English), while most of those with regular forms have been introduced more recently. For example, "vet" is fairly [new](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2008/09/when-did-we-start-vetting-political-nominees.html), originating from the late 19th century and surprisingly seems to be related to "veterinarian".

**Irregular**

let: from Old English lǣtan (Wiktionary)

bet: from 16th-century criminal slang, likely from abet or Old English bætan (Wiktionary)

set: from Old English settan (Wiktionary)

hit: [from late Old English](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=hit) hyttan, hittan

**Regular**

vet: [late 1800s](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2008/09/when-did-we-start-vetting-political-nominees.html)

jet (as a verb): [1690s](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jet), from French jeter "to throw, thrust"

net (as a verb): [1400s](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=net)

pet: [Sense of "to stroke" is first found 1818](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pet)

wet: from Old English wætan (*This may be an exception, but as noted in a comment, the irregular past form "wet" is used in some senses.)

Answer (score 0):

WaterMolecule's answer seems to be right in attributing the difference to historical causes. There seem to be complicated reasons for the development of the two kinds of inflection for verbs ending in *-t* or *-d.*

#### Verbs that originate from "class I weak verbs" tend to contain the vowel E and have irregular past-tense forms ending in T or D

It seems that the verb *set* was a [class I weak verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_weak_verb#Class_I,_subclass_(iii)) in Old English. Verbs of this class originally had a *-j-/-i-* suffix that caused umlaut on the vowel (which explains why many of them have the vowel *e*). But not all of the irregular verbs like this end in *-et*: there are also ones ending in *-it* (such as *knit,* although it also has an alternative form *knitted*) and *-ut* (*shut*).

The presence of this *-j-/-i-* suffix was relevant to the development of the past tense form because the *i* vowel in the past tense form eventually ended up being lost, causing the past-tense suffix to come directly after the consonant at the end of the verb root. When the verb root ended in *t* or *d,* the final consonant of the verb root merged with the past-tense suffix (or the past-tense suffix was dropped), and shortened the preceding vowel if it wasn't already short.

*Meet, bleed, breed, feed* all have long vowels in the present tense, and *set* has a short vowel in the present tense, but historically, these verbs all belonged to the same conjugation class.

#### The development of other classes of verbs is also relevant

There was another class of weak verbs where it appears to have been usual for the past tense to end in *-ed.*

And there were also several classes of strong verbs that had members ending in *-d* or *-t* that developed irregular past-tense forms similar to those seen in class I weak verbs. *Let* is in this category, as is *shed.*

An account of the history of these verbs is given in "[The Regularization-Through-Derivation Effect and the Historical Development of Verbs in the
West Germanic Languages](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~fertig/PubsTalks/FertigDerivAndRegPaper.pdf)", by David Fertig:

> The distinction between regular and irregular weak verbs in modern English is a partial continuation of the distinction between Class-2 and Class-1 weak verbs in OE, and thus ultimately a partial continuation of the distinction between verbs formed with the *-ja*-derivational suffix and those formed with *-ō-*. [...]  In early Middle English, after reduction of unstressed vowels, the descendents of the class-2 (*-ō-*) verbs had a connecting schwa before the dental suffix in the past tense, whereas in the descendents of Class-1 (*-ja-*) verbs, the dental suffix was generally attached directly to the end of the verb stem, with no connecting vowel. [...]
>
> Many of the T/D+Ø weak verbs in Modern English were Class-1 verbs in Old English, including *spit, knit, shut, set, sweat, wet, spread,* probably *slit,* perhaps *cut,* and partially *put.*
>   Others were from Old Norse, borrowed into OE as Class-1 verbs and first attested (with no connecting schwa) in early ME, including *hit, thrust, cast,* and *rid*. Still others were strong verbs in OE and apparently owe their T/D+Ø past forms to reanalysis of the suffixless strong past.
>   These include *shit, burst, let, bid,* and *shed*. Finally, *quit, cost,* and *hurt* were borrowed from French into early Middle English at a time when the general inflectional-class distinction between verbs with and without a connecting schwa was still very much alive. Most French borrowings were conjugated with a connecting vowel, including most of those ending in *-d* or *-t*, such as *butt* ('hit'), *mend, tend, fend, plead, treat, cheat, pleat, waste, taste,* as well as others that rhymed with weak verbs of the no-connecting-vowel class, such as *glean*. A considerable minority entered the no-connecting-vowel class, however, for reasons that are not entirely clear. In any case, 22 of the 25 verbs in the modern T/D+Ø class belonged to the no-connecting-vowel class in early Middle English. The modern irregular forms of these 22 verbs therefore have nothing to do with any analogical attraction of the T/D+Ø class. Only three verbs appear to have genuinely been attracted into that class: *split* was borrowed from Dutch in the late 16th c.; *bet,* of controversial origin, is also first attested in the late 16th c.; and *fit,* originally derived from the adjective in the late 16th c., has, in the 20th c., developed T/D+Ø forms in certain meanings.
>
> Similarly, *breed, bleed, feed, lead, read, speed* and *meet* are all from OE weak class 1, making *plead* the only verb that has (in some dialects) been attracted into this subclass. Among the other T/D-with-laxing verbs, *hide, light,* and *alight* were in weak class 1 in OE, while the
>   remaining three, *slide, bite,* and *shoot,* were strong.

(pp. 20-21)

It seems that verbs ending in *-t* or *-d* that were formed after the Middle English era have mostly followed the *-ed* pattern.