# what is the past tense of "I beat him" - here beat refers to striking a person

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

Lets say I am beating a person continuously, this is a present participle.
What do I say when I have to convey that I have been beating him in the past - "I beat him badly" ?? How do I pronounce it ?

Comment: Why do you think “bet”  may be correct?

Comment: _Beat_ is one of those [one-syllable verbs ending in _-t_ or _-d_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/397616/15299) (like _set, bet, bid, burst, cast, cost, cut, fit, hit,_ and so on). They are spelled the same way in all three forms (add _-ing_ for the participle, as usual), and they are also pronounced the same way. So it's not a situation like _lead, led_, or _lead_ the noun; spelling is irrelevant and pronunciation is the same. _I beat him badly_ could be present tense or past tense. These verbs don't care.

Comment: @JohnLawler One method to definitively state the tense for these verbs is to use the continuous tense: "I am beating him," "I was beating him," "I will be beating him."

Comment: It's one participle. _Beaten_  is another, but the _-en_ participles are regularly shortened.

Comment: @TylerN: Why would anyone want to definitively state the tense? Tenses are relics in English and are rarely important; usually we prefer constructions uninflected, or uninflectable like modals. One of the reasons why there is this set of small verbs is that they are used so much in constructions where the tense is irrelevant (or even where the construction indicates the time itself). In such cases tense inflection is a nuisance when it's not automatic on every verb, but only on third-person singular present verbs.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul OED: “The Old English past tense *✻béot* (representing earlier reduplicated *✻bebôt*,
*✻baibaut*), duly became in Middle English *bēt, bete* (with close *ē*, as
distinct from the open *e* or *ę* of the present); its modern form would be
*beet*, but this became obsolete in 16th cent. 

The actual past tense *beat* is
probably shortened from the Middle English weak form *beted*, in 16th cent.
*beated*.” [NB: Here *actual* means current or present-day, being the elder sense for that adjective. —tchrist]

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul  OED: “The **past participle *beat*, still occasional for *beaten* in all
senses,** but chiefly used in sense 10, and in phrases like ‘dead-beat’
belonging to that sense, may also be < *beated*, but comes naturally enough
from Middle English *bet*, shortened < *bete, beten*, found already in 13th
cent., and having the open *e* of the present.”

Comment: The exact same sentence could be present or past depending on context. It's not conjugated differently. But I think the present tense version of this sentence would be rarer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are conveying that you have previously beat him, you would say:

> I beat him.

If you want to convey that you were actively beating him for a length of time, say:

> I was beating him.

The present tense of beat is "beat," and the past tense of beat is also "beat." All usages of this word are pronounced the same way:

bēt (beet)

Also, natural English speakers would more often use the phrase "beat up," rather than "beat" alone, because "beat" could be used for its second definition of:

> defeat (someone) in a game, competition, election, or commercial venture

To use this phrase, you would instead say either

> I beat him up.

Or

> I was beating him up.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [the already present answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/540894/388094), if you are talking about a length of time that is entirely in the past and it happened customarily, in idiomatic English, you could also use (or add) *would* to express that:

> I would beat him [up] [often, regularly, etc]

and

> I would be beating him [up] often [*as part of this toxic relationship, whatever*]

ETA: The *would* would, then, often be abbreviated to "***I'd***". Mostly so in speaking, could also happen in writing depending on context and style.